# why variable value is not updated inside function . in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am sending a function as props in reactjs .I have one state "form submitted" or "not submitted". I am getting wrong output (console output) inside the function . don't know why ? But outside function I am getting correct value.

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-dawn-0uu62q?file=/src/nested.tsx

```
const NestedComponent = () => {
  const { registerState, formState } = useHookFormContext();
  console.log(formState.isSubmitted, "outside");

  return (
    <>
      <CustomApi
        key={"abc"}
        options={[]}
        onChange={() => {
          console.log(formState.isSubmitted, "inside");
          console.log("sss");
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

steps to reproduce bug

- run application . see console it will show **false** which is correct.
- Click submit button . see console it will show **true** which is correct.
- Now change the dropdown value .see console it will show **false** value which is incorrect correct. why is showing different value

[image]

is it closure issue ???

Comment: The outer code runs once per component instance. Presumably when you change the dropdown it causes the `NestedComponent` to be replaced by a new instance. You didn't provide that code, but likely the `isSubmitted` attribute isn't set on the component when it is created. Perhaps `isSubmitted` should be an attribute of the parent component, not the `NestedComponent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with this release of [mui-react-hook-form-plus](https://github.com/adiathasan/mui-react-hook-form-plus) - v1.3.5

Forgot to reassign the `onChangeRef` in each render cycle. Hence closure got the prev value

```
+ const onChangeRef = React.useRef(onChange);
+ /**
+  * we update the ref on every render
+  */
+ onChangeRef.current = onChange;
```

example: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-nova-ur0rv8?file=/src/nested.tsx